# I want to get right value from list

Tags: linq, list, class, console

I have a list where I put in some values to different class properties, and then I am use a linq query to sort out specific value.

```
            List<Artikel> Minlista = new List<Artikel>();

        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Mjölk", Pris = 14.90, kategori = new Kategori {Namn = "Mejeri"}, });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Apelsin", Pris = 7.90, kategori = new Kategori { Namn = "Frukt" } });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Skinka", Pris = 20, kategori = new Kategori { Namn = "Kött" }, });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Räkost", Pris = 33, kategori = new Kategori { Namn = "Mejeri" }, });
        Minlista.Add(new Artikel { Varonamn = "Köttfärs", Pris = 45, kategori = new Kategori { Namn = "Kött" }, });

        var specifikvara = from item in Minlista
                    where item.Pris < 34
                    select item;
        foreach (var item in specifikvara)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
        }
```

This is supposed to find a price (Pris in swedish) that is less then 34. I get 4 "values" into my var specifikvara, and then I print it out. But I want to print out the name of the artikel (Varonamn) but I only recieve this message on the console "Consoleapplikation1.Artikel". How can I change it so it writes out "Skinka" or "Räkost" or any of them?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting bunch of `Artikel` type objects, that's why you are getting the default `ToString()` value. You can either:

```
1. select item.Varonamn 
2. Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Varonamn);
3 override ToString in Artikel object
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `item` in the loop is of type `Artikel`. If you need to print its name, print the attribute that has the name:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Varonamn);
```

You can reference other attributes, too:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", item.Varonamn, item.Pris);
```

Comment: Oh god it was that easy? crist. Thanks a bunch :)